# How do I install a new language pack for Tesseract on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, python-tesseract

I have installed the `pytesseract` module in my `venv` and want to extract text from a German image.

Eith executing this script from
[pytesseract](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract) and setting the language to German

```py
import cv2

import pytesseract


try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.jpg')))

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.jpg'), lang='ger'))
```

which gives me

```
raise TesseractError(proc.returncode, get_errors(error_string))
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.05.00dev with Leptonica
 Error opening data file C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR/tessdata/ger.traineddata
 Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'ger\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')
```

I have found the language data on [tessdoc/Data-Files] (https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/master/Data-Files.md)

So far I only found a guide for Linux [How do I install a new language pack for Tesseract on 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793634/how-do-i-install-a-new-language-pack-for-tesseract-on-16-04)

Where do I need to move the language files in my `pyteseract` sitepackage to get the script working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a guide to do this on a german site [Python Texterkennung: Bild zu Text mit PyTesseract in Windows](https://computer.meinwissen.info/python-texterkennung-bild-zu-text-mit-pytesseract-in-windows/)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways.

#### 1. Install the corresponding tesseract package for your language -

- `apt-get install tesseract-ocr-YOUR_LANG_CODE`

for example- in my case it was Bengali so I installed -

- `apt-get install tesseract-ocr-ben`

or for installing all languages -

- `apt-get install tesseract-ocr-all`.

This worked for me Ubuntu environment.

#### 2. The other way is mentioned in the error message itself. Add an environment variable `TESSDATA_PREFIX` that point to the langauge pack. You can download the language pack from here: `https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata` .

Once you have downloaded the datapack you can also programmatically set the environment variable as

```py
import os
os.putenv('TESSDATA_PREFIX','path/to/your/tessdata/file'
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way I've found:

1. Download and install `tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.0.0-rc1.20211030.exe`.
2. Open https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata and download your language. For example, for Farsi download `fas.traineddata`.
3. Copy the downloaded file to the `tessreact_ocr` installation location, some location like: `C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata`
4. Don't forget to use the `traineddata` name for the language. For Farsi, I use `lang='fas'`.